# Convert an audio file into raw binary data in javascript

Tags: javascript

How to convert an audio file into raw binary data in javascript?

Comment: No, I need to do it in javascript

Comment: Uh... what for? A bit of context would be good. What do you want to *do* with the raw binary data?

Comment: Is this from a web browser or using a local javascript interpreter like rhino? If it's from a web browser, you need to edit your question and say which one, since the mechanisms to allow local file access depend on the browser. Or if your web browser is running locally you should mention that too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Local file access with javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371875/local-file-access-with-javascript)

Comment: if you end up using Flash, there is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243912/read-local-file-in-flash

Comment: Hey its not about accessing local files ... its about conversion of an audio file...

Answer (score 4):

Use the [File API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799665/html5-file-api-availability-and-abilities).

With Blob data, you can get a Uint8Array or whatever other typed array you like.  Here's a [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_typed_arrays/Uint8Array) to more info about Uint8Arrays.

You might also be interested in [this](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Audio_Data_API).

Comment: ooh, thank you! nice to know, I missed this while looking at new features

Comment: I've been messing with binary data lately in JavaScript. Just happened to know a few good resources.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create handler that will do the job the javascript will only call the handler with the right parameters according to what you need look at jquery ajax call: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/